# Почему не удается выборочно объединить элементы массива в строку?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Допустим есть массив

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Я хочу объединить выборочно несколько элементов массива в строку (оставив остальные элементы на месте). Для примера использую аргумент '+'

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

arr.slice(1, 2).join('+');
alert (arr);
```

Я ожидал получить `"1, 2+3, 4"`.
Почему этого не происходит?

Comment: [Метод slice() возвращает поверхностную копию части массива в новый объект массива](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: @norbornen Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы хотите, это следующее

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

arr.splice( 1, 0, arr.splice(1, 2).join('+') );
alert(arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!... но я не очень понял почему) видимо ДР сказывается). То есть здесь мы говорим: начиная с индекса 2, удалить 0 элементов, и добавить (2 объединенных элемента, начиная с индекса 1)... почему при этом не получается "1, 2, 2+3, 4"? Вызывая splice внутри splice мы заменяем те элементы, которыми оперируем?

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Сначала удаляются 2 элемента, начиная с индекса 1. Они объединяются в строку и добавляются в позицию 1 того же самого массива, но уже без удаленных элементов.